# Cascade DACs to get higher resolution

Tags: dac

I got a RAM-DAC with 3 channels and 6 bits for each channel. The device in question seems very straightforward to use with a modern MPU like an AVR.

The resolution is a bit low, so I thought about cascading the three channels with a R-2R-ladder. Does that work with current-output-type DACs?

Comment: Generally not a good idea as the noise in the higher bits may swamp the lower - what is the application, video, audio or something else?

Comment: simple frequency generator with some spare parts lying around. highest precision is not necessary ; but more than ~8 bits resolution would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put:  No.  It doesn't work that way.  In theory, yes.  In practice, not so much.

There are two main issues:  Noise, linearity, and timing.

Nose is the easiest to understand.  Noise in the first DAC will be added to noise in the second, resulting in more noise.

Next is linearity.  The DAC has more than just noise on the output.  Let's say that you have a 2 bit DAC, so it outputs 4 levels.  It should output 0%, 33%, 66%, and 100%.  Instead it might output 0%, 25%, 82%, and 100%.  This will make combining the output of the DACs together more difficult to do while increasing accuracy.

Timing is also difficult.  And by that, I mean getting the various DACs to output the correct data at exactly the same time.  If one DAC outputs it's new value slightly ahead of the 2nd DAC then you could end up with noise and spikes where you don't want any.

Use the correct DAC for your application and you will be much happier.

Answer (score 2):

The fact of the matter is that there has been well know topologies and matching techniques for doing Video DAC's in CMOS process for at least 25 years now.  DAC's are extremely easy to implement with good manufacturing yield and low noise.

But fundamentally your answer is unanswerable, because the specifics are important and you've given none, and once you have the specifics you'll quickly be able to calculate what the performance is.

I can't say yes, this will absolutely work, because they may have done some silly things in the design OR they have some different constraints.  However, if they've designed the DAC using bog standard techniques or grabbed a cell from a standard library you should be able to easily get at least a 4X improvement from 6 bits to 8 bits.

The best thing is to look at the datasheet for INL, DNL and output noise in terms of  DN and particularly a DNL plot would be best.

Should you design a production unit like this?  Probably not.  Experimenting? why not?  It's likely to work and you have nothing to lose.

Comment: INL is +-0.5 LSB, the full scale error is maximum +-5 % (relative to external reference), offset error is +-0.5 LSB, too. DAC-to-DAC-matching is specified with +- 2.5 %... so I could do this by giving each output their own load resistance to get a voltage from the current outputs and then putting a R-2R-ladder in front of this, right?

Comment: I'm really saying that there is no reason why you shouldn't play around with it, at the very least you'll learn something.  Your proposal seems OK, but it depends upon whether the design can sink/source or only source current.  If it's only sourcing then make sure that the R-2R ladder doesn't change the load resistor value the DAC sees.  So maybe a buffer map is the right thing to do after the load resistor.  The DAC to DAC matching seems harsh so maybe have room in there to add in trimming resistors in parallel.